# How to solve "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

***When i try to run npm start in my react app i got this ERROR :***

```
$ npm start

> trends@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Administrateur.TEST\Desktop\reactProjects\trends
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! trends@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the trends@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrateur.TEST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-20T07_09_04_578Z-debug.log
```

I tried other solutions, like using clean cache, deleting node_modules & run npm install again, but still got the same ERROE

Comment: can you add version of `create-react-app` you are using

Comment: @Yassine, According to create-react-app docs, don't download create-react-app using `npm install -g create-react-app` rather run it directly using `npx create-react-app`

Comment: Yes, that's what i have done at first place

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing these three steps:

1. `npm install -g npm@latest` to update npm because it is sometimes buggy.
2. remove `node_modules` folder in your project.
3. `npm install` to re-install the project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by adding C:\Windows\System32\ in PATH SYSTEM VARIABLES